# What is the intrinsic distance of an open and dense subset of the plane?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, optimization, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be an open, connected, dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Consider $U$ as a Riemannian submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with the Euclidean metric), and let $d_U$ be the intrinsic distance induced on $U$, i.e. the distance between any two points $p,q \in U$ is the infimum of lengths of paths connecting $p,q$ that stay inside $U$.

**Does $d_U$ equal the Euclidean distance, or can it be larger for some pairs of points?**

---

This is asking whether we can maneuver around the points in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus U$, with arbitrarily low "cost" in length, no matter how "ugly/nasty$ $U$ is.

Of course, if $U$ is the entire plane after excluding a finite number of points, the answer is positive (and easy).

Comment: I may miss something... How can $U$ be finite and open, apart from being empty?

Comment: Thanks, I confused the phrasing: I meant for $U$ to be the entire plane after excluding a finite number of points. (So I was in fact describing the complement of $U$). Fixed now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A counterexample: $U = \mathbb R^2 - \{(x,0) \mid x \le 0\}$

Comment: Though what if $\mathbb R^2\setminus U$ is nowhere dense?

Comment: Thanks, nice example. I guess my intuition was for the case where $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus U$ has Hausdorff dimension zero. I wonder what happens in that case.

Comment: There is a little typo: you surely mean $\Bbb R^2$, not $\Bbb R$ right?

Comment: Oops, kind of a glaring typo too!